# How can I overwrite the localities in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a Method that uses an array with certain numbers of localities. I ask for the user to input the number of the locality to start overwriting. My object array has other objects in the localities. I'm not sure if what I am doing with the j variable is correct. The following is my way of moving the objects in the localities.

```
public void overwriteArray(int number) {
  for (int i=0; i<array.length ; i++) {
    if (i ==(number-1) {
      for(int j = i ; j<array.length ; j++) {
        array[j] = array[j+1];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any other way? Is there something easier than using arrays? Is correct the way of moving the objects in the array?
Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you want a `List` instead of an array.

Comment: Yep, arshaji is right, a List would provide this functionality (and much much more) right away...

Comment: but i must use an array, is specified like that D:

Comment: @Pony it is not clear whether `number` is normal human counting i.e. `1, 2, 3, ...` or an index i.e. `0, 1, 2, ...`

Comment: normal human counting

Answer (score 0):

Your outer loop iterates over the hole array and execute  the inner loop only when `i == (number-1)` so `array.length - 1` of the iterations are for free!

You could get rid of the outer for loop along with the `if (i ==(number-1) {` and  instead write `for(int j = (number-1) ; j<array.length ; j++) {`

also `array[j+1];` will give you an [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) on the last iteration. Maybe you will want to go only till `array.length - 1`.

Also to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` you should make sure that `number` is within the range `[1, array.length]` before iteration.

Here is how could looks like:

```
@Test
public void overwritearrayay() {
    String[] array = {"foo", "bar", "foobar"};
    log(Arrays.toString(array));
    overwritearrayay(array, 1);
    log(Arrays.toString(array));
}

public void overwritearrayay(String[] array, int n) {
    if(n > 0 && array != null && n <= array.length) {
        for(int i = n-1; i < array.length-1; i++) {
            array[i] = array[i+1];
        }
        array[array.length-1] = null;
    }
}

public static void log(String string) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

**Output**

```
[foo, bar, foobar]
[bar, foobar, null]
```

Comment: @ppeterka66 you mean [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(boolean[])) ;-) I don't know the APIs by heart :/ and in my IDE I started with `Arrays.asS` and hit `Ctrl + space` for auto complete (analogy `Arrays.asList(...)`) and it gave me nothing ...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well: you want to remove the element described by the `number` input parameter, and shift the remaining elements to the left. Also, the element on the end stays in place with all moves. And number is the number of the element to be removed, so **1** means, the **1st element** is to be removed, meaning the **index of 0 **in the array, am I right?

Then your code seems to work OK, with the exception, that you don't need the outer loop. At all:

```
public void overwriteArray(int number) {
  for(int j = number-1 ; j<array.length ; j++) {
    array[j] = array[j+1];
  }
}
```

The outer loop didnát do anzthing, except when the loop variable was exactlz `number-1` Also beware, this might address outside of the array length...

You could use [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) for this purpose too, no need for this lenghty code (the indexes might be off, and of course it would dies with improper `number` argument):

```
public void overwriteArray(int number) {
    System.arraycopy(array, number, array, number-1, array.length-number);
}
```

It *does* work on the same src and dest:

> If the src and dest arguments refer to the same array object, then the copying is performed as if the components at positions srcPos through srcPos+length-1 were first copied to a temporary array with length components and then the contents of the temporary array were copied into positions destPos through destPos+length-1 of the destination array.